# Asking the question in the question title

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there anything wrong with questions like [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)? Personally I feel it looks a bit untidy, but I'm not sure what I'd put in the question body. Clearly the user has just put something because they're obliged to, although it doesn't add any information that the tags don't already convey. Should we expect some kind of background about the users photography experience be included in this case?

I can't come up with any real improvement to this, but it doesn't *feel* like the question has been asked in the best possible way, somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally a question contains too little information if it fits in a reasonably short title.

Comment: _Generally_ perhaps, but it should not be discouraged if the person has taken the time and effort to distil the essence of a question into a single, succinct sentence.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is anything wrong *per se*; personally I try to restate the question and include the rationale as to why I'm asking, or what I've tried. There's nothing more frustrating than giving an answer that the original person dismisses it as they'd already tried something (but not said that)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the greater picture of how this family of websites is used, I try to craft a title that would contain the question, phrase, or terms most likely to be used by someone performing a google search.

In the example linked above, I can't think of a better title than the one used by the question-asker.

Answer (score 1):

I think the example is a legitimately short question. What else could be added? I wouldn't worry unless it starts happening a lot.

Also, there's no need for a question to be asked in the "best possible" way. We should be satisfied with questions simply being asked well.

It's really too bad the asker misspelled "Canon", though. :/

Comment: The biggest problem is that most of us cannot yet edit and fix the question due to our low reputation :(